# Elegant representation of dictionary with aligned equality sign

Tags: python

I want to print the representation (**repr**) of a python class as follows:

```
varA         = 0.5
variableB    = 0.242
var_cadateta = 'test'
```

where the equality signs are nicely aligned. I don't want to count every time I change a variable name, so I would like to automate this in a function. For instance, is there a way to do this easily with a dictionary or does this need to be handcrafted?

I can get the max length using

```
var_max = max(len(k) for k in variables_dict.keys())
```

and probably take it from there, but I was hoping for a more pythonic way

Comment: That's a fine way to write it, IMHO. You could also do `len(max(variables_dict.keys(), key=len))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a general purpose prettyRepr function for any dictionary and use it in your class's **repr** method or anywhere else:

```
def prettyRepr(d):
    return "\n".join(f"{k:{w}} = {v}" for w in [max(map(len,d))] for k,v in d.items())
```

Example uses:

```
varA         = 0.5
variableB    = 0.242
var_cadateta = 'test'

print("globals:")
print(prettyRepr(globals()))

def myFunction():
    varD         = 1.5
    variableE    = 3.14
    varamatras   = 'hello'
    print(prettyRepr(locals()))

print("\nLocals:")
myFunction()


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = 32
        self.property = "world"

    def __repr__(self):
        return prettyRepr(self.__dict__)

c = MyClass()
print("\nClass repr:")
print(c)
```

output:

```
globals:
__name__        = __main__
__doc__         = None
__package__     = None
__loader__      = <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
__spec__        = None
__annotations__ = {}
__builtins__    = <module 'builtins' (built-in)>
__file__        = /Users/****/Documents/Python Scripts/playground.py
prettyRepr      = <function prettyRepr at 0x10e0c4378>
varA            = 0.5
variableB       = 0.242
var_cadateta    = test

Locals:
varD       = 1.5
variableE  = 3.14
varamatras = hello

Class repr:
prop1    = 32
property = world
```